# React object how to wrap more than one component

Tags: reactjs

This would cause an error:

```
test = {
   a: <div></div><div></div>
}
```

while this is all right:

```
test = {
   a: <div></div>
}
```

so how to wrap two componet in the same key in react?

Answer (score 7):

Use a `React.Fragment`:

You can do it like this:

```
test = {
  a: (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Shorthand:

```
test = {
  a: (
    <>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </>
  )
}
```

React fragments allow you to render sibling children together without rendering anything in the DOM.

The only prop that `React.Fragment` can take is a `key` prop which you would use if you plan on wrapping items in a mapped array. This prop can't be used in the shorthand version.

You can [read more about Fragments here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

---

You can also accomplish it without a `React.Fragment` like this:

```
test = {
  a: [
    <div></div>,
    <div></div>
  ]
}
```

But this method isn't as easy to read as the Fragment solution and you can't assign it a `key` prop if needed. Fragments are the best practice solution according to React's documentation.

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy Coding :D

Comment: @KevinWade could you mark my answer as correct please?

Answer (score -1):

```
test = {
     a: <div> 
          <div></div> 
          <div></div>
      </div>
}
```

Comment: This adds an extra `div` to the DOM which is not what the OP wants.